# How to increment a colums value, when a call and value both passed to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, referral and user model.

> Referral belongs_to User AND user has_one Referral

When a user signs up, they are given a unique referral, like this `localhost:3000/absc`
where `absc` is the unique referral Id.

When another users visits, `localhost:3000/absc`, using the `routes.rb` I have extracted the Id as follow

```
match '/:ref_token' => 'user#new'
@ref_token = params[:ref_token]         #in users_controller.rb
```

Now I have a `hits` column in `Referral`, that should increment the value for referral id `absc`, for each visit to the URL.

How can I do so elegantly.

This may seem trivial, but I'm still on my path to Ruby Enlightenment, and I seek your wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, simply do :

```
Referall.find_by_ref_token(params[:ref_token]).increment!(:hits)
```

Comment: Referal Model does not has :ref_token as id of the model and it says Couldn't find Ref with id=gs7z1x7x

Comment: Man !! rails is just awesome.. I dunno, how can I really learn it well.

Comment: This statement should belong to model, how do I do that.